# Convert column into comma-separated list

Tags: sql

For context, I'm pretty new to SQL.

I'm doing a Leetcode problem #608, don't want it solved for me, but here it is for reference:

https://leetcode.com/problems/tree-node/

The table has 2 columns:

```
id: int
p_id: int
```

I basically want to see for each `id` value whether or not it exists in the `p_id` column.

I tried the following to test this:

```
SELECT id NOT IN (p_id) 
FROM tree
```

What I want is, using [this input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvu6w.png) as reference, is an output of (1, 1, 0, 0, 0) Boolean values.

However, from what I currently UNDERSTAND, this doesn't work because the column p_id is not in a comma-separated list. Is there a way to convert a column into a comma separated list? Or is there another way to approach this to get my desired outcome?

Comment: Remember that in the select clause you show data from one row at a time. This means you are looking at a row's id and p_id. This means `id NOT IN (p_id)` is the same as `id <> p_id`. You want to select all p_id from the table instead in order to look for the id in that data set.

Comment: Going to a comma-separated list in a database is the wrong direction, an anti-pattern even: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/1115360) (TLDR: yes).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use a a cooma seperated list or simply make a sub select like

```
 SELECT id  from tree WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT p_id FROM tree)
```

The result set acts like the list